# Custom Control for displaying multiple items in text field

Tags: webforms

I'm looking for an Asp.Net WebForms custom control that allows users to select items from a drop-down and add them to the text part of the control. And at the same time provide users with a means of removing an item from the text field similar to the way Stackoverflow does with tags.

Thanks